# Using complicated conditional logic to route in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I'm an absolute newbie to Dialogflow. I have a complicated need in Dialogflow CX and want to know if there is a way to achieve what I want. Here's a made up use case that reflects my needs (explaining my whole need is too complicated). I'm creating a restaurant ordering app and the user has a "favorite order" saved already in the database that has several items they want to order. The app already has looked up various items the user wants to order from the database and wants to allow the user to customize things about each item in the menu. The detectIntent call is invoked with a custom parameter called "items" that has a comma separated string of all the names of the items that the user wants to order.

The customizations are item specific so there is an intent for customizing each item in the menu. The agent has to check if "items" has a particular item-name and invoke the customize_ intent and keep doing this till all the items are processed.

There is a root intent called "Customize Items" that asks a question "would you like to customize your items?" and if the answer is "yes", it now has to invoke the customize_ intent for each item in the "items" parameter.

If there is a good way to achieve this irrespective of what I'm trying below, please let me know. But this is what I'm trying and am stuck in not knowing how to do a few things:

Pass in three additional parameters with initial values as shown below while invoking detectIntent:

```
finished_customizing_items" = ""
items_to_customize = <total number of items in the "items" string>
customized_item_count" = 0
```

In the "customize items" intent, there are conditions that route to each customize_ intent. Condition reads as:

```
customize = 'yes' AND
items_to_customize > customized_item_count AND
items HAS(:) <item_name> AND
finished_customizing_items DOES NOT HAVE <item_name> THEN
route to customize_<item> route
```

In the customize_ route:

- Capture all customizations
- Append <item_name> to finished_customizing_items
- increment customized_item_count

Finally, in the "Customize Items" intent, add another condition that says:

```
items_to_customize == customized_item_count THEN
route to FINISH
```

I don't know how to do "DOES NOT HAVE" in the condition, don't know how to modify an existing parameter (increment customized_item_count and append <item_name> to finished_customizing_items). After I figure out all this, I'd like to know if you find any other problems in my approach that needs fixing.